# What is a good program for optimizing images on a website?

Tags: images, optimization

I have some extensive website that I need to analyze the images and see if they can be optimized. Can any one recommend a good program for this?

Comment: optamizing should be optimizing please update your topic.

Comment: This question, while on topic is seeking opinions rather than an exact answer. I've converted it to community wiki.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe Photoshop has a pretty good optimizer built in. (Save for web & devices) An older version of it is Adobe ImageReady if you can find it in a bargain bin somewhere.

Comment: +1 - ... and don't forget batch processing

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+S (save for web) shortcut :)

Comment: @JP Hellemons - anything that requires 4 keys depressed simultaneously is not a shortcut IMO. My mouse is functional, and I don't need to be able to play Rachmaninoff on my left hand in order to pull it off. The .078 seconds saved simply isn't worth the savings.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [PNGCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) and [Smush.it](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/).

Answer (score 2):

+1 for smush.it, if you use the firefox addon Yslow http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

it has smush.it built in as part of its optimization arsenal. It offers further file savings in addition to photoshops 'save for web' feature.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested a few programs last week, on my tests [PNGOUT](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm) produced the smallest PNGs.

Note that you can get even better results by modifying the image, especially by reducing the number of colors used.

Answer (score 1):

I find that photoshop is lees effective than online tools. If you compromise with 80% quality of image then its size can be reduced to half.

Better way is to take a good resolution image then compress it using some onine tools as suggested here. Then use Office image viewer to resize and compression.

I hope u'll get what you want

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS X, I love [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.pornel.net/)